# How to add legend and make lines random color as a new line is added to D3.JS

Tags: d3.js

Every time I add to the below dataset a new line is addedd to my chart. What changes do I need to make in order for this to be a different random color each time, and how/where should I add a legend for thes random lines?

Working Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/qvrL3ey5/

```
var dataset = [
[{ x: 0, y: 100  }, { x: 1, y: 833  }, { x: 2, y: 1312 }, { x: 3, y: 1222 }, { x: 4, y: 1611 }],
[{ x: 0, y: 200  }, { x: 1, y: 933  }, { x: 2, y: 1412 }, { x: 3, y: 1322 }, { x: 4, y: 1711 }]]
```

Code:

```
var dataset = [
[{ x: 0, y: 100  }, { x: 1, y: 833  }, { x: 2, y: 1312 }, { x: 3, y: 1222 }, { x: 4, y: 1611 }],
[{ x: 0, y: 200  }, { x: 1, y: 933  }, { x: 2, y: 1412 }, { x: 3, y: 1322 }, { x: 4, y: 1711 }]]

var margin = { top: 20, right: 100, bottom: 30, left: 100 },
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(series) {
        return d3.max(series, function (d) { return d.x; })
    })])
   .range([0, width]);

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(series) {
        return d3.max(series, function (d) { return d.y; })
    })])
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)
    .ticks(0)
    .orient("bottom")
    .outerTickSize(0)
    .tickPadding(0);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(yScale)
    .orient("left")
    .outerTickSize(0)
    .tickPadding(10);

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function (d) { console.log(d.x, xScale(d.x));return xScale(d.x); })
    .y(function (d) { return yScale(d.y); });

//Create SVG element
var svg = d3.select("#visualisation")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top     + ")");

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis)

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)

svg.selectAll("path.line").data(dataset).enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("d", line);
```

**Edit:**
Found how to add the color..

```
var color = d3.scale.category10();

    .attr("d", line)
     .style("stroke", function (d) {
         return color(d);
```

Still researching how to add a legend.

**Edit:**

Unfortunately the color's are the same, unless the data-sets are different lengths.. If I have data-set A) 25 points and B) 30 points it generates two different colors, but if both A&B are 25 points then its the same color.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the colours: `var color = d3.scale.category10()` will create a ordinal scale with empty domain and range with ten colors, but if no domain is set the domain will be automatically created according to the sequence you call `color`. So, we have to set a domain:

```
var color = d3.scale.category10();
color.domain(d3.range(0,10));
```

And then painting the lines randomly:

```
.style("stroke", function (d) {
     return color(Math.floor(Math.random()*10))});
```

This satisfies your request for the lines:

> to be a different random color each time

Check this fiddle, every time you click "run" the colors are different: https://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/qvrL3ey5/1/

Regarding the legend, you'll have to give us more information.